# Safe to use int in multithreaded single writer multi-reader code

Tags: c++, concurrency, stdatomic

I'm writing parallel code that has a single writer and multiple readers.  The writer will fill in an array from beginning to end, and the readers will access elements of the array in order.  Pseudocode is something like the following:

```
std::vector<Stuff> vec(knownSize);
int producerIndex = 0;
std::atomic<int> consumerIndex = 0;
```

Producer thread:

```
for(a while){
  vec[producerIndex] = someStuff();
  ++producerIndex;
}
```

Consumer thread:

```
while(!finished){
   int myIndex = consumerIndex++;
   while(myIndex >= producerIndex){ spin(); }
   use(vec[myIndex]);
}
```

Do I need any sort of synchronization around the producerIndex?  It seems like the worst thing that could happen is that I would read an old value while it's being updated so I might spin an extra time.  Am I missing anything?  Can I be sure that each assignment to myIndex will be unique?

Comment: This is definitely a data race on `producerIndex`, which is read from one thread and written in another.

Comment: Yes, but it seems like it's a "benign race," where the consumer could read either the old value or the old value + 1, both of which are OK here.  Is it possible to read some value that was never actually stored in producedIndex?

Comment: @BenJones a race is undefined behavior.  It could be the old value, it could be a new value. But it could also be a mix of the wo (the new upper byte and old lower byte).  Or it could crash, or produce other weird things.

Comment: I think you are mixing producer-consumer and writer-readers problems. In the first each produced item is consumed by only _one_ thread, while in the second several readers may be accessing the same element. Solutions are different for each problem.

Comment: @Christophe that's what I wanted to know.  Standard says "The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior." So I guess I need to make producerIndex atomic as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, this code has a data race. Instead of speculating about whether the code has a chance of doing what you want, just fix it: change the type of `producerIndex` and `consumerIndex` from `int` to `std::atomic<int>` and let the compiler implementor and standard library implementor worry about how to make that work right on your target platform.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the array will be stored in the cache so all the threads will have their own copy of it. Whenever your producer puts a new value in the array this will set the dirty bit on the store address, so every other thread that uses the value will retrieve it from the RAM to its own copy in the cache.
That means you will get a lot of cache misses but no race conditions. :)

Comment: This isn't how modern CPU's work (caches co-operate; RAM is too slow), but from a C++ perspective you can't tell the difference.